# Cookies are not getting set when running with --host option in official SvelteKit example

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying offical SvelteKit example https://realworld.svelte.dev/.
Its code is hosted at https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld

login and everything works fine when I run `npm run dev`
but when I run `npm run dev -- --host` then login does not work.

```
cookies.set('jwt', value, { path: '/' });
```

This is not working so cookies are not getting set so login is not working.

How can I make login working when using `--host` option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're blocked from logging in when addressing the exposed network IP URL (`localhost` should still work) on an unsecured (`http`) connexion.

The reason for this is because the default cookie configuration in SvelteKit is to set the `secure` option to `true`, meaning cookies won't get set upon unsecured requests. From the [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-cookies):

> The httpOnly and secure options are true by default (except on http://localhost, where secure is false), and must be explicitly disabled if you want cookies to be readable by client-side JavaScript and/or transmitted over HTTP. The sameSite option defaults to lax.

As you can see, this explains why the default configuration works on `localhost` (where `secure` is `false`) but not on the exposed network IP address (where `secure` will be `true`).

If you update the cookie configuration in `src/routes/login/+page.server.js` to explicitly set the `secure` option:

```
cookies.set('jwt', value, { secure: false, path: '/' });
```

and restart your server, you should then be able to login as expected from the exposed network IP URL (I was able to).

**Note:** in a production deployment, you *will* want the `secure` flag set to `true` and use a secure protocol (`https`) for your requests.

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/75087582/1762051

Comment: Anyone struggling with setting the cookie in expressjs server, this is the right answer. Change the flag to false and cookie will be set. In sveltekit load, log fetch headers.headersList and cookies are the first entry in headersList. Note the capitalized L in list.