# Host sveltekit adapter-node generated build with nginx proxy_pass on path other than /

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I want to serve [sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) build generated from [adaptor-node](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node) via [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) `proxy_pass` with address `mydomain.com/dashboard_v2`

`svelte.config.js` is

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        csrf: { checkOrigin: false },
        paths: {base: '/dashboard_v2'}
    },
};

export default config;
```

I am building using `npm run build`
I am running using `npm run preview -- --host`

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com` is

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name mydomain.com;

       root /home/ubuntu/website;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

        location /dashboard_v2/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4173/dashboard_v2;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                # WebSocket support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.trimpixel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.trimpixel.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This config is giving `too many redirect` error.

This build is working fine under `location /` but not wokring under `location /dashboard_v2`

What changes are needed to make `location /dashboard_v2` work?

Comment: When running on production, use `node build` and not `vite`.
As for the nginx config, I'm unsure but I think a `location` config needs to exist to have the fallback page set to `index.html`
Reference: https://sdickinson.com/nginx-config-for-single-page-applications/

Answer (score 1):

Hello for what I know the code for https, needs to be in a separate server block .

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.trimpixel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.trimpixel.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and from the server that listens port 80 you redirect to 443

you can check [this](https://github.com/woollysammoth/sveltekit-docker-nginx) repo for a full example