Storing cookies host network url (SvelteKit application)
I am building a SvelteKit application with authentication. The authenticator is a local SurrealDB database. When i try to login or signup to my application using the host url 192.168.1.20:5173, the authentication token that i recieve and store in cookies, is not stored afterall after authentication.
This is my login action:
// src/routes/login/+page.server.ts:
login: async (event) => {

    const form = await superValidate(event, zod(formSchemaLogin))
    
    if (!form.valid) return fail(400, { form })

    let { username, password } = form.data

    let result = await db.getTokenFromLogin({ username, password })

    if (result.err) {
        return redirect(
            { type: "error", message: result.err.message },
            event
        )
    }

    let { token } = result.val

    event.cookies.set(TOKEN, token, { path: "/" })

    throw redirect(303, "/home")
},

I type in my authentication details into my form, and i successfully recieve an authentication token from the database. I store this token in event.cookies.set(TOKEN, token, { path: "/" }) .
This is my hook for controlling protected pages:
// src/hooks.server.ts
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    
    let { cookies, url, locals } = event

    if (url.pathname == "/") throw redirect(303, "/login")

    let token = cookies.get(TOKEN)

    ... use token to check if client is allowed to certain pages ...

    return resolve(event)
}

When i login using localhost:5173 and console.log(token), i see the authentication token in the hook. But when i try this by logging in with 192.168.1.20:5173, i see that there is no token stored in the cookies, eventhough i see (using console.log) that the authentication is successfull in src/routes/login/+page.server.ts .
I run my application using npm run host, and i have the script "host": "vite --host" in my package.json . When i run the application, these are the urls that i can use:
  VITE v5.2.8  ready in 2747 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.1.20:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://172.19.80.1:5173/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help


I found this question with an answer, but setting ´secure: false’ did not work for me… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045021/cookies-are-not-getting-set-when-running-with-host-option-in-official-svelteki

If I'm not mistaken (from a previous question you asked about HMR), you're running SvelteKit as a dockerized app? Remember that if you're changing the server-side configuration (and that includes editing any .server.ts page), you will likely have to restart the server (and rebuild your Docker image if you're running in a container). The only obvious explanation I can see that would make the localhost version work vs. the IP-based one not working is indeed the absence of the secure flag in the cookie configuration, for the reason mentioned in the answer you linked (which I wrote).

Considerate of you to remember my other last post, haha:) I went away from that idea, i can see that i do not need the application dockerized in dev mode. But anyways, this is very wierd, because im running simple npm run host as explained above, and i reset my server, after having set secure to false. There cannot be any further settings missing? I’ll have a look at this again when i get the time, double check and try it again, then i’ll let you know here.
